# Replicate multiple times a set of rows with unique column in a table

Tags: sql-server, cursors

I wish to replicate a set of rows in a table but with handling unique column in SQL Server 17.
The table is:

```
CREATE TABLE test1 (
    id int CONSTRAINT PK_test1 PRIMARY KEY  CLUSTERED IDENTITY,
    name nvarchar(10) CONSTRAINT UK_test1 UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED,
    value int,
    type varchar(20)
);
```

The table contents are:

```
INSERT INTO test1 VALUES ('e_1',1,'A');
INSERT INTO test1 VALUES ('342A',34,'ABC');
INSERT INTO test1 VALUES ('Tame_33',277,'Test10');
```

Now I wish to replicate those rows multiple times but the problem is with NAME column which is UNIQUE.
The solution I did so far is just use of a cursor, but this is inefficient and I'm curious if this can be done in more efficient way?

```
DECLARE @id int;
DECLARE @name nvarchar(20);
DECLARE @value int;
DECLARE @type varchar(10);
DECLARE @cnt int = 0;stackoverflow
DECLARE @intcnt int = 0;

DECLARE temp_cursor CURSOR FOR
SELECT * FROM test1
OPEN temp_cursor;
FETCH NEXT FROM temp_cursor INTO @id,@name,@value,@type;

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    WHILE @intcnt < 5
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO test1 VALUES
        ('ins_' + CONVERT(varchar,@intcnt) + '_'  + CONVERT(varchar,@cnt), @value, @type);
        SET @intcnt = @intcnt + 1;
    END 

    SET @intcnt = 0;
    
    FETCH NEXT FROM temp_cursor INTO @id,@name,@value,@type;
    SET @cnt = @cnt + 1;
END

CLOSE temp_cursor;
DEALLOCATE temp_cursor;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
WITH gen AS (
    SELECT 1 AS num
    UNION ALL
    SELECT num+1 FROM gen WHERE num+1<=5
)
INSERT INTO test1 (name,value,type)
SELECT 'ins_' + CONVERT(varchar,num) + '_'  + CONVERT(varchar,id), value, type 
FROM gen
CROSS JOIN test1
```

Some explanation provided by the OP, added so others can adapt the solution:

> Actually used CTE as a generator of integers (called
> 'fnTally') which he later used in CROSS JOIN to produce cartesian
> product of those two tables - the source one which is 'test1' and
> generated by CTE called 'gen' (a combination of every row from two
> tables). The only further optimization here would be to use cCTE
> (cascade CTE introduced by Itzik Ben-Gan).